# How to set correct file permissions with CGI::Session

Tags: perl, session, cgi

For anyone else reading this; it seems the issue was caused by permissions and suexec was part of the issue.  Having disabled suexec, all is well again (subject to consequential issues I may find later).

Two files I have in (say) dir1, in /cgi-bin/dashboard-login/  and they use CGI::Session to manage the session.

Both files set a new session like this:

```
my $session = new CGI::Session(undef, $cgi, {Directory=>"$sessions_dir_location"}) or die CGI::Session->errstr;
```

This means the second file is actually opening the session created by file1. All good so far.

File 3 is in the same sub-domain but in a different dir (/cgi-bin/dashboard/).  It also runs that session string but I get the following error:

```
Software error:
new(): failed: load(): couldn't retrieve data: retrieve(): couldn't open '/var/www/vhosts/example.com/sessions_storage/cgisess_fc6c62eee135f6cd418defef4516a59c': Permission denied at index line 38.
For help, please send mail to the webmaster (root@localhost), giving this error message and the time and date of the error.
```

In Filezilla, I see that the file permission is set to "dfr (0640)" for the latest session file but, the previous one has the permissions "adfr (0640)"  That adfr file can be opened in filezilla and didn't have any issues when I ran my scripts.  Now the session files are being created as "dfr (0640)". IS there a way to set the server (or the CGI::Session), to apply "adfr (0640) permissions?

And, in your experience, is that the likely cause of the problem?

Comment: Can you provide more information on the permissions on the various directories and files: What is the output of `ls -l /var/www/vhosts/example.com/sessions_storage`, `ls -l /cgi-bin/dashboard-login`, and `ls -l /cgi-bin/dashboard`

Comment: Glad you got it to work. Instead of editing the solution into your question, please write your own answer and accept it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go  Håkon Hægland

ls -l /var/www/vhosts/myDomain.com/sessions_storage

-rw-r-----. 1 MyUserName       psacln  166 Jan 26 01:22 cgisess_0741489d1010b7ab36f86420e5c58e84

-rw-r-----. 1 apache           apache 1769 Jan 26 12:35 cgisess_2d475576f960f6c5407d7a273c02ead1

ls -l /var/www/vhosts/domainName.com/subDomain.myDomain.com/cgi-bin/dashboard-login

-rwxr-xr-x. 1 MyUserName psacln 30628 Jan 26 01:46 login.pl

-rwxr-xr-x. 1 MyUserName psacln 48391 Jan 26 00:49 login-with-pin.pl

ls -l /var/www/vhosts/domainName.com/subDomain.myDomain.com/cgi-bin/dashboard

-rwxr-xr-x. 1 MyUserName psacln  40742 Jan 24 17:47 web_content_manager

For anyone else reading this, it was a permissions issue. It seems to relate to SuExec. Having disabled SuExec, temporarily, until I learn more about directory locations and permissions fully, all is well again.